# Error installing JSHint/JSLint into Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext, jslint, jshint

I am trying to integrate jsHint or jsLint into Sublime Text 3 using Package Control.

But a Python syntax error keeps coming up. I haven't edited any script in the package or Sublime Text itself. I have never run Python in Sublime Text as well.

I originally planned to install it on a USB, but it didn't work. I assumed the error was due to the program not being in a hard drive. It still doesn't work on my laptop.

---

**OS:** Windows 8.1
jsLint package: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSLint
jsHint package: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSHint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you include the following with your question:

1. Python syntax error you refer to in your question
2. Details about your environment (OS at minimum)

Without it, I can speculate that you have installed the Sublime Text package that has an unfulfilled dependancy.

If you installed the most popular JSLint package for Sublime Text, [JSLINT](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSLint), then you also need to have node.js installed.

Comment: Hm... I didn't know JSLINT requires node.js. I have installed it and I will see if this fixes my issue.

Comment: Also useful to say *which* JSLint package you/OP used -- deridder or fbzhong -- and which JSHint. ;^)

Comment: @ruffin Updated question with the info.